# How to reset singleton instance?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a singleton instance like this

```
static let currentUser = User()

private override init() {
    super.init()
    // custom initialisation
}
```

How can I reset this instance or set back to nil?

Comment: Add a method that recreates the initial state.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I create all my Singletons with an `optional` Singleton instance.
However I also make this `private` and use a function to fetch it.
If the Singleton is `nil` it creates a new instance.

This is actually the only good way to set up a Singleton. If you have a regular object that you can't deinitialize it's a memory problem. Singletons are no different, except that you have to write a function to do it.

Singletons have to be completely self managed. This means from init to deinit.

I have a couple of templates on [github](https://gist.github.com/romainmenke/468168b87de2131847cf) for Singeltons, one of them with a fully implemented read/write lock.

```
class Singleton {

    private static var privateShared : Singleton?

    class func shared() -> Singleton { // change class to final to prevent override
        guard let uwShared = privateShared else {
            privateShared = Singleton()
            return privateShared!
        }
        return uwShared
    }

    class func destroy() {
        privateShared = nil
    }

    private init() {
        print("init singleton")
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit singleton")
    }
}
```

Comment: @R Menke your implementation in Github is not Swift 3 compatible

Comment: @JAHelia I have long since given up on updating Swift code. I even stopped writing Swift al together because Apple keeps breaking everything.

Comment: @RMenke does your implementation works well for well known multithreaded issue?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Nope

Answer (score 11):

You can not do that if you declare `currentUser` as `let`.  It should be `var` instead, or better still `private (set) var`.  Also you can not assign `currentUser` with `nil` if its type is `User` (inferred from the way you assign it at the moment).  Instead, it should be `User?`.

For example, something like this:

```
/// ...

static private (set) var currentUser: User? = User()

static func resetCurrentUser() {
    currentUser = nil
}

// ...
```

`private (set)` allows changes to the property only within the scope of current file, and for the rest of your code it will be seen as `let`.  Then method `resetCurrentUser()` can be used to put it to `nil`.

---

Or even this:

```
// ...

private static var _currentUser: User?

static var currentUser: User {
    if _currentUser == nil { _currentUser = User() }
    return _currentUser!
}

static func resetCurrentUser() {
    _currentUser = nil
}

// ...
```

You can have `currentUser` as computed property that guarantees to return a value.  So you can reset the user to `nil`, yes.  But if later you will try to read from there again a new instance will be created automatically.

Be careful with multithreaded access, though.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is working, but if you want to not deal with optionals you can create a `private` setter:

```swift
class Singleton {

    static private(set) var shared: Singleton = Singleton()

    static func reset() {
        shared = Singleton()
    }

    private init() {
        print("init singleton")
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit singleton")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for me the best solution: I don't need to de-init a singleton, but I need to reset it for unit tests. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

All you want is possible, but highly unrecommended :) Because singletons by design should not fall back to nil.

First, if you want to change `currentUser`, it must be `var`. Then if you want it to be nil, it must by optional type and you should unwrap it when using.

```
static var currentUser: User? = User()
```

I would propose to not change `currentUser` or make it non-static (for example, a property of some `UsersManager`.

Also you can change properties of `currentUser` (like `name`, `loggedIn`). At last, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28398974/326017 - it describes your situation.